# How to: New order Binance API via RStudio

Tags: r, api, sha256, hmac, binance

I am trying to create a new order via the Binance API using RStudio.

I found the Binance Official API Docs and figured out that I should use

```
POST /api/v3/order (HMAC SHA256).
```

The following script doesn't work out for me:

```
url='https://api.binance.com/api/v3/account'

GET(url, 
    add_headers("X-MBX-APIKEY"= *[my API key]*),
    query=list("symbol"="ETHBTC", 
               "side"="BUY", 
               "type"="MARKET", 
               "quantity"=1, 
               recvWindow=5000, 
               "timestamp"=1499827319559, 
               "signature"=**???**), 
    verbose())
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong and how I can create an order via the Binance API using RSTUDIO and how I can create my signature?

Comment: It says POST but you're doing a GET

Comment: As @HongOoi said, start by replacing GET with POST. Then an initial investigation strategy would be to do `r <- POST(url, ....` followed by `str(r)`. Look at the status first: is it a `20x` or a `40x` or sth else? Then look at the rest, might be informative as well. (Also, the documented entrypoint seems to be `order`, why are you using `account`?)

Comment: Many thanks HongOoi and Aurèle, My bad. I did use 'order' as entrypoint, but typed it wrong here by mistake.

@Aurèle, what do you mean with str(r) and the 20x and 40x status? I'm sorry but I am not that experienced yet with R. Maybe you can give an example of how the script should be?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes. By `str(r)` I mean: type this in an R console to examine what's in the `r` response object. I cannot give a full example here in the comments but https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/vignettes/quickstart.html is a very good resource for a start

Comment: Great @Aurèle, your help is pretty much appreciated!

Comment: @Aurèle, do you also know how I can generate my signature in RStudio?

Comment: Maybe sth along the lines of: `query <- list(
  "symbol" = "ETHBTC",
  "side" = "BUY",
  "type" = "MARKET",
  "quantity" = 1,
  recvWindow = 5000,
  "timestamp" = 1499827319559
) ; signature <- digest::hmac(key = "my-secret-key", object = paste(names(query), query, sep = "=", collapse = "&"), algo = "sha256") ; 
POST(url, add_headers("X-MBX-APIKEY"= *[my API key]*), query = c(query, signature = signature), verbose())`

Comment: Hi @Aurèle, I executed all steps as you mentioned above. When performing < content(r, "text") I get the following message:

[1] "{\"code\":-1021,\"msg\":\"Timestamp for this request is outside of the recvWindow.\"}"

Do you have an idea how to solve this (latency??) issue?

Comment: I don't know. Try with increasing values for `recvWindow`. I don't have an account to try out things with this API and I don't know its details. Try googling the message + "binance"

Comment: Thanks. I found out that I should use server time - 2000 as my timestamp. If I check the server time with GET /api/v1/time I get this message: [1] "{\"serverTime\":1526487412388}" 

I need to assign this number minus 2000 to my timestamp, but how can I calculate with the server time in this form?

Comment: `as.character(jsonlite::fromJSON("{\"serverTime\":1526487412388}")$serverTime - 2000)` ? Unfortunately the comments on SO are not the place for extended discussions and follow-up questions. Maybe ask your follow-up questions in separate SO questions.

Comment: @Aurèle, it all works out perfectly well. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Bart You're welcome. Maybe I'll write out an answer out of those comments, for reference, or feel free to do it yourself and accept your own answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(httr)

timestamp <-
  as.character(jsonlite::fromJSON(content(
    GET("https://api.binance.com/api/v1/time"), "text"
  ))$serverTime + 999)

query <-
  list(
    "symbol" = "VENBTC",
    "side" = "BUY",
    "type" = "MARKET",
    "quantity" = 1,
    "recvWindow" = 5000,
    "timestamp" = timestamp
  )

signature <-
  digest::hmac(
    key = "*[my secret key]*",
    object = paste(names(query), query, sep = "=", collapse = "&"),
    algo = "sha256"
  )

POST(
  url,
  add_headers("X-MBX-APIKEY" = "*[my API key]*"),
  query = c(query, signature = signature),
  verbose()
)
```

Comment: You may want to add some explanation to this answer. On one hand that helps when "repeating what you've learned", on the other it improves the answer for future visitors that come across it. 

Lastly it can transfer information from comments (which are subject to irredeemable and silent deletion) into a more permanent record

Comment: Hi, I used your code to place an order but it does not work, I got an error message (x-cache: Error from cloudfront). I have tried also using Binancer package, but it doesn't work as well, any idea?